# HSI formula inconsistency in Gonzalez & Woods

Tags: image-processing, color

I'm confused about how the book Digital Image Processing by Gonzalez & Woods explains HSI model. It includes a double cone-shaped space for the model (like the figure below) and says every color on the perimeter of the middle circle has intensity 0.5. These include red, green, and blue.
[image: HSI model]

At the same time, it says that the I component is derived by averaging R, G, and B. The RGB representation of red is (1, 0, 0) which makes its intensity 0.33, while is inconsistent with the above paragraph.

Am I missing something? Is it an error in the book? Or what?

Comment: good question. in other words  converting the red point in above figure with H=0, S = 1 and I = 0.5 does not result in (255,0,0) RGB and is result  in clipping